# Multiple results for condition in ternary javascript operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

Is there a way to append a display:none style object onto a ternary operation in javascript?

I have this

```
leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 2 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : leftContent.innerHTML;
```

Which works to display content into my leftContent div, but I want to be able to also set other divs to 'display:none' like so

```
leftColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
```

within the same operator, so I'd say 'if panel_type_id = 2, set leftColumnQtrHalf and rightColumnQtrHalf to none'

Is that possible?

Comment: Why not just use an ordinary `if` statement?

Comment: Best practice for readability: use the `if` and try not to be too clever

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a bit doubtful what you actually wanna achieve but you can do something like:

```
leftColumnQtrHalf.style.display = rightColumnQtrHalf.style.display = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 2 ? 'none' : 'block';
```

Comment: See that removes my innerHTML content though. I was trying to make it to where if the id is 2 I would still do the innerHTML for the content but also hide other divs